# iOS Admob - How to add Ad that is ALWAYS under the navigation bar even when navigating pages?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, admob

I would like an Admob ad to be displayed below my navigation bar in my app. The whole app is built using a navigation controller so no view controller would be without it.

Google recommends that we don't load a new ad on each page as it's better to keep the same ad going for the whole time it has.

I would like the SAME ad that loads to be moved between every view controller below the navigation bar. I want it to take up space so that the content of any tableviews etc start AFTER the ad.

I read that you can create a bannerview in storyboard, so I tried to create a view on the navigation controller in the storyboard, but storyboard wouldn't let me drag any views on the navigation bar, only the specific view controllers.

How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do being making the same Ad appear on every view controller in the navigation stack?

Not sure if this matters but the app is iOS 11 with Xcode 9 beta. Using objective-c.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the same add below your navigation bar - then you need to subclass from UINavigationController and add this view programatically. Ant that view will called like this - "GADBannerView *bannerView;".

Comment: Do you have an example? I'm not familiar with the method you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

This might be really overdue, but I found a way to do something similar. You can't drag and drop a view into the TabBar in the storyboard but you can add the AdMob Banner programmatically once you create a custom view controller for your UITabBarController.

First - Create a custom UITabBarController file for your project and link it to the actual UITabBarController you have in your storyboard.

Second - Add the implementation code from Google to display the AdMob Banner ad.

This should allow the ad to persist on all tabs of your UITabBarController.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that the second part where you create the admob banner should be in the custom UITabbarcontroller that the tab bar inherits from? I'm thinking what you are trying to do is have any instance with this custom UITabbarcontroller automatically create an add to display?